# Strange JavaFX NPE "Location is required"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am building a large JavaFX application with a lot of scenes and am now trying to deploy the application with Maven.

Maven expects resources, e.g. FXML files, to be placed under `src/main/resources`. This currently clashes with the way I am loading new scenes into my main scene container.

I am utilizing a small framework by jewelsea to load new content: [Small JavaFX framework for swapping in and out child panes in a main FXML container.](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130)

This approach has worked flawlessly so far. However, now that I am trying to fetch the resources (the FXML files) from `src/main/resources` I am running into NullPointerExceptions.

I can load my `MAIN` view just fine using the approach below but all other views throw NPE's.

The `MAIN` scene is loaded like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Pane mainPane = loader.load(getClass().getResource(ViewNavigator.MAIN));
MainController mainController = loader.getController();
ViewNavigator.setMainController(mainController);
ViewNavigator.loadVista(ViewNavigator.CONFIGURE);
```

Take note of the last line. I use the function `loadVista` to inject the `CONFIGURE` view. This function is declared in the `ViewNavigator` class:

```
static void loadVista(String fxml) {
    try {
        mainController.setVista(
                FXMLLoader.load(
                        ViewNavigator.class.getClass().getResource(
                                fxml
                        )
                )
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the *exact* same approach is used to fetch the `CONFIGURE` scene but this time I run into an NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3246)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
at com.demant.controller.ViewNavigator.loadVista(ViewNavigator.java:33)
at com.demant.controller.MainController.configureView(MainController.java:99)
... 58 more
```

Inside the `ViewNavigator` the URL's to the `MAIN` and `CONFIGURE` views are declared like this:

```
static final String MAIN      = "MainControllerView.fxml";
static final String CONFIGURE = "ConfigureView.fxml";
```

I have, hopefully obviously, placed my resource files under `src/main/resources` and marked the package as a *resources root*.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Open up a file browser and look in your build folder (`target/classes`, I think, is the default when using Maven). That should help you understand where everything is placed at runtime, given the setup in your source hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FXML files are loaded at runtime, so in a sense the organization of your source code hierarchy is completely irrelevant; the only thing that is important is the content of the classpath. Of course, your IDE, via Maven in this case, is determining how source code and resources in the source hierarchy are compiled and deployed to what will become the classpath hierarchy.

So to make this work, there are two things you need to understand: first, what is the eventual location in the classpath of the various resources defined in your different source folders, and second, how does `Class.getResource(resourceName)` resolve the specified `resourceName` to find a resource.

For the first question, Maven likes to separate Java source files, which need to be compiled to class files, from other "static" resources. (This makes sense in web applications, where these are often deployed to different locations; imho it makes much less sense in a desktop application; however that is somewhat off-topic.)

Java source code, by default, is in a folder `src/main/java`. Source code in that folder is compiled and the resulting class files are deployed to the build folder (which by default is `target/classes`). The usual rules about Java packages apply, so if you have a class `Main` in a package called `org.example`, the source code will be in `src/main/java/org/example/Main.java` and the compiled code will be in `target/classes/org/example/Main.class`.

Non-Java resources, again by default, are placed in `src/main/resources`. Files in this folder are deployed (i.e. copied) to the same build folder. Consequently, if you have an FXML file, say `Sample.fxml` and you want it to end up in the package `org.example`, you would place it in `src/main/resources/org/example/Sample.fxml`. When the project is built, it will be copied to `target/classes/org/example/Sample.fxml`.

For the second question, a `Class` instance has a `getResource(resourceName)` method that will return a URL representing the resource. (So, if you are running from classes in the file system, it will return a URL with a `file:` scheme; if you are running from a jar file, it will return a URL with a `jar:` scheme, etc.) I like to think of `Class.getResource(...)` as meaning "Find the resource in the same place you found the current class". If your resource name is *absolute*, meaning that it begins with a leading `/`, then the resource is searched for from the root of the classpath. If the resource name is *relative*, i.e. it doesn't begin with a `/`, then the resource is searched for from the package for the current class. Note that the components of resource names (the pieces between the `/`) must be valid Java identifiers. In particular, this means you cannot assume you are loading resources from a file system (usually you aren't), and names containing `.` and `..` are invalid. So you can only search in the current class's package, subpackages of that package, or using absolute resource names.

Here's a simple example. Suppose we're making the usual demo JavaFX program with contact information. We need (at least) a main class, which I'll call `ContactApp`, an FXML file, `Contacts.fxml`, and a controller class, `ContactController`. I will put the main class `ContactApp` in a package called `org.jamesd.fxtest`, and the controller class in a subpackage, `org.jamesd.fxtest.contacts`.

I like to put FXML files in the same package as their corresponding controller classes (the advantage of this will become apparent shortly), so `Contacts.fxml` is also going to go in `org.jamesd.fxtest.contacts`.

Here's a screenshot of the project layout for this:

[image]

To confirm these are being deployed as expected, use a system file browser (Finder, Windows Explorer, etc) to look in the "build" folder, which by default is `target/classes`:

[image]

As you can see, as expected, the FXML file and the controller class are deployed to the package `org.jamesd.fxtest.contacts`, and the main class is deployed to `org.jamesd.fxtest`.

To load the FXML file from the `ContactApp` class, I could specify an absolute resource name (again, this means relative to the classpath):

```
URL location = getClass().getResource("/org/jamesd/fxtest/contacts/Contacts.fxml");
```

Alternatively, I could use a relative resource name. Since the current class is in `org.jamesd.fxtest` and the resource I want is in `org.jamesd.fxtest.contacts`, the following will work:

```
URL location = getClass().getResource("contacts/Contacts.fxml");
```

The approach I prefer is to place the FXML file in the same package as its corresponding controller. The benefit to this is that I can use the controller class to load the resource. An advantage here is that it's much easier to refactor things, as the code is less dependent on the actual location of the FMXL file (any IDE will handle refactoring imports easily). Here's an entire `ContactApp` class using this approach.

```
package org.jamesd.fxtest;

import java.net.URL;

import org.jamesd.fxtest.contacts.ContactController;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ContactApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        URL location = ContactController.class.getResource("Contacts.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(location);
        Parent root = loader.load() ;
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

So in your example, I would recommend placing your FXML files in the same package as `ViewNavigator`: this means that if `ViewNavigator` is in the package `com.demant.controller`, then the FXML files go in `src/main/resources/com/demant/controller`. Then simply using `ViewNavigator.class.getResource("ConfigureView.fxml")` should work. If it doesn't work, then you can open up `target/classes` in a system file browser to diagnose the problem.

Finally, note that you want

```
ViewNavigator.class.getResource(...)
```

not

```
ViewNavigator.class.getClass().getResource(...)
```

In the latter code, `ViewNavigator.class` resolves to an instance of `Class<ViewNavigator>`, and so `ViewNavigator.class.getClass()` resolves to an instance of `Class<Class<?>>`. Since `Class` is in `java.lang`, you would be searching in the classpath for `java.lang.ConfigureView.fxml`, which clearly doesn't (and shouldn't) exist.

Comment: Thank you for your very elaborate answer! I followed your suggestions and now the program compiles and runs like it should. Appreciate the added bonus of going into detail which gave me a lot more insight into the class path and the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `getResource` on `Class.class`. (`ViewNavigator.class` evaluates to the `Class` object containing the info for the `ViewNavigator` class and `getClass()` returns the type of this object.) The `getResource` is therefore looking for the resource in the path `/java/lang/ResourceName`.

You need to use the `ViewNavigator` class to resolve the resource though:

```
mainController.setVista(
        FXMLLoader.load(
                ViewNavigator.class.getResource(
                        fxml
                )
        )
);
```

or use absolute paths:

```
static final String MAIN      = "/com/demant/controller/MainControllerView.fxml";
static final String CONFIGURE = "/com/demant/controller/ConfigureView.fxml";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Changing `ViewNavigator.class.getClass()` to `ViewNavigator.class.getResource()` doesn't make a difference. It is still throwing the same NPE. Also, I cannot use the paths you mention because Maven expects the FXML files to be in the `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: @kdhansen You do use the same package structure below the resource root though. (At least that's what the working code snippet suggests. Or what's the class containing the code loading the main fxml?) The only thing i can think of without more info is a typo in the resource name.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to get at. Prior to implementing Maven in order to deploy the app I was using those exact paths for my FXML files, as in `"/com/demant/controller/MainControllerView.fxml"` which worked. However, now that I am using Maven in order to deploy, I have put my FXML files under `src/main/resources` because Maven expects these files to reside here when compiling and packaging. What baffles me is that the `MainControllerView.fxml` file can be located just fine in the `src/main/resources` folder while the others cannot. I can't find any typos anywhere. I'm stumped!

Comment: The class file loading the `MainViewController.fxml` resides under `src/main/java/com/demant/controller/MainController`. I have java marked as _sources root_.

Comment: @kdhansen Your FXML files should be in a folder such as `src/main/resources/com/demant/controller/MainControllerView.fxml`. This assumes `ViewNavigator` is in the `com.demant.controller` package. Setting `src/main/resources` as a "resources root" means the contents will be deployed to the root of the classpath. At runtime, `ViewNavigator.class.getResource(...)` will search relative to the location of `ViewNavigator` in the classpath, i.e. it will search in the package in which `ViewNavigator` is defined. (For an absolute path, it searches relative to the classpath.)

Comment: @James_D Thank you for the reply. I've added the folder structure you mentioned and put the views there. The `ViewNavigator` still resides in `src/main/java/com/demant/controller/ViewNavigator`. Are you then suggesting that the path for my view's inside the `ViewNavigator` class should be changed to `"/src/main/resources/com/demant/controller/MainControllerView.fxml"?`. Could you possibly elaborate on why the `MainControllerView.fxml` can be located when it is placed in `src/main/resources` but the `ConfigureView.fxml` cannot?

Comment: @kdhansen No! If `ViewNavigator` is in the `com.demant.controller` package, then `ViewNavigator.class.getResource("ConfigureView.fxml")` will look in that package at runtime, i.e. it will look for `com/demant/controller/ConfigureView.fxml`, relative to the *classpath*. If `src/main/resources` is a "resources root", the contents of `src/main/resources` will be deployed to the classpath, so in your source code hierarchy you would place `ConfigureView.fxml` in `src/main/resources/com/demant/controller`. Then `ViewNavigator.class.getResource("ConfigureView.fxml")` should work.

Comment: @kdhansen I can't explain why `MainControllerView.fxml` is working - maybe you have a copy of `MainControllerView.fxml` in another location in your *build* hierarchy, left over from an older build, that is being read? Just a blind guess.

Comment: @James_D Thank you. I'll try to implement your suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

in your fxml file you need to specified the controller to be used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import java.util.ArrayList?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.MyController">
    <Label  fx:id="label1"/>
    <Label  fx:id="label2"/>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply, however, in all my FXML files I have already declared which controller to be used. This is an excerpt from my MainControllerView.fxml:

[...] fx:controller="com.demant.controller.MainController">